# ZFS 0.8.0 on Ubuntu or Debian

Tags: openvpn, zfs

I recently built a new NAS server using FreeNAS after searching to see if anyone had done the things I wanted to do with the server and because I liked the things ZFS does. Now I find that the latest version of FreeNAS does not allow some of the things older versions did or if it does nobody on the FreeNAS forums can tell me, or at least is willing to tell me, how to make it work.

In any case I would like to move back to Ubuntu but keep the ZFS Pools I created in  FreeNAS. Unfortunately it seems that the version of ZoL which is available in Ubuntu does not offer the same features (device removal, obsolete counts, and zpool checkpoint) so I would only be able to import the Pools read only at best.

ZoL 0.8.0 seems to have those feature but its only on RC3 and I am worried what the implication might be to install it as far as stabily and bugs go. I also wonder how I go about installing it. Can I install from the the [tar.gz](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/releases) or do I need to compile it?

As a side note, the main thing I could not get working on FreeNAS was passing traffic from various Jails through an OpenVPN Jail so that I didn't need to install OpenVPN on all of the Jails that required it.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to stick with FreeNAS for the time being and wait until ZoL 0.8.0 is finalised unless the stable 0.7.x is an option and you can temporarily live without those features. (I'm not sure from your statements whether you've updated FreeNAS and found that features are not available anymore, in which case a downgrade might be an option, or whether you did not yet update, in which case you might want to simply choose not to until you find a solution.)

The size of the userbase is a *very* important criterion! (I have not seen "that many" people discussing the migration from FreeNAS to a ZoL(*RC*)…) Apart from that, switching to ZoL 0.8.0RCn means you're basically opting to become a beta tester (assuming that you're currently not using some test version of FreeNAS)–is that really what you want to do with your time? (Not saying the world does not need beta testers, but if it's not one of your main objectives in this context…)

Even if everything was supposed to work, you'd need to create a backup of your pools to be safe–then, why not simply recreate them in the first place?